# заполнить таблицу, но что туда заполнять?

Tags: ассемблер

[image: ---]

программу написал и теперь требуется заполнить эту таблицу. но что заполнять в неё непонятно(ОП1,16сс что это вообще такое?)

Comment: ну мнемоника и машинный код это понятно, а вот как относительный адрес выглядит?

Comment: ОП1, ОП2 - операнд1, операнд2, 16сс - 16-ричная система счисления. Относительный адрес команды - адрес команды относительно чего-то (начала программы, например). Относительный адрес операнда - это в случае если один из операндов является адресом в памяти.